# Abrir archivo txt en python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando abrir un archivo .txt en python que contiene una lista de coches, sus precios y su año de fabricación. Sin embargo, con este código:

```
file= open('c:users/documentos/texto/coches2021.txt', 'r')
print(file.read())
```

No se abre absolutamente nada, pone que es correcto y encuentra el archivo, pero no se ve el texto. ¿Por qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: Cambia `c:users/documentos/...` por `c:/users/documents/...` (la diagonal después de `C:` y el directorio en inglés). `Documentos` es solo un alias de `Documents`.

Comment: te falta una / entre el disco y users

Answer (score -1):

Hola Luisa un gusto en saludar, bienvenida a la comunidad

Tienes que asegurarte la ruta donde tienes el archivo, y podrías también agregar el encoding por si estás en un crossover Windows/Linus

```
with open('<Ruta del archivo>/file.txt', encoding="utf8") as file_data:
    data= file_data
data
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda

Comment: Gracias Maotse, probaré a ver si así puedo abrirlo!

Comment: No entiendo por qué el voto fue negativo.... ???

Answer (score -1):

Solo debes recorerr el archivo para leer todas las líneas, prueba:

```
for a in file:
    print(a)
```

Comment: ¿Por que el voto negativo? Si algo no es correcto corrijan, pero no vayan votando así porque sí.

Comment: No soy el votante y no veo nada malo en tu respuesta. Solo se me ocurre que quiza tu respuesta es corta y eso tienta a los que recien pueden votar a votar negativo. Espero que alguien mas se le ocurra alguna cuestion que a mi no. Sobre la explicacion, es un laaargo debate en las redes de stack exchange. Y gana por ahora el que explicar sea opcional. Yo estoy en contra.